Some specific smooth functions vanishing of infinite order at 0 must vanish identically
I've come across a problem in my complex analysis course as below:

Let $M:=\left\{M_k\right\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a logarithmically convex sequence of positive numbers; that is
$$
M_k \leq M_m^{\frac{n-k}{n-m}} \cdot M_n^{\frac{k-m}{n-m}}, \quad \forall m<k<n .
$$
Denote by $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ the set of infinitely differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Set
$$
C_M(\mathbb{R})=\left\{u \mid u \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \quad \exists C_1, C_2 \text { such that } \sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{d^k u}{d x^k}(x)\right| \leq C_1 C_2^k M_k, \forall k=0,1,2, \cdots\right\}
$$
Suppose that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{M_k^{1 / k}}=\infty
$$
Prove that for any $u \in C_M(\mathbb{R})$ vanishing of infinite order at $0$ must vanish identically on $\mathbb{R}$.

As it's from complex analysis course, I think it's necessary to prolonge u into set $\mathbb{C}$. However, I find it difficult to find any property of u after that. I've found some papers about logarithmically convex sequence but don't give me any more inspiration.
I found some arguments about smooth function vanishing of infinite order at $0$, so I think this problem can give a sufficient condition to some good result.
Can anyone help me with this problem? Any hints or ideas are welcome. You have my thanks.

This is (part of) a well known theorem (Denjoy Carleman) on quasi analytic classes of functions - Rudin has it in the last chapter if I remember right

@Conrad Thanks for the hint. In fact, it is in the Chapter 19, Section 19.6.

Happy to be of help
